# Worklight settings in Action bar then no other activity can be displayed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, ibm-mobilefirst

I am having trouble with my action bar. I am able to display my actions in action bar and also display worklight settings in it, but never together.

Whenever I set the worklightSettings = true in application descriptor, nothing that I've define in the app/res/menu/menu.xml is displayed in the actionbar. When I set the worklightSettings = false, everything from app/res/menu/menu.xml is in the actionbar, as it should be,but the worklightSettings(obviously).

I am using the implementation similar to this:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/native_ui_in_a_hybrid_application_with_worklight_6.2?lang=en

(nexus 7,kitkat,minSDKversion=14)

Answer (score 0):

The Worklight Settings option is designed to work only with the OptionsMenu UI widget Android. By enabling it, it will not be displayed in the Action Bar (an unsupported UI widget by Worklight, which you can add per the blog post you've linked to).

If you are using MobileFirst 6.3, there is now API to control the server URL (either set or get it). The API is available for both Hybrid (iOS, Android) and Native (iOS, Android, WP8) applications. So you could combine your Action Bar code with this API w/out using the Worklight Settings option.

See this blog post for an example using the Hybrid API: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/02/changing-server-url-runtime/

Comment: When I set it the WLsettings to false I have everything I need in the action bar. Thats why I know it works

Comment: Right, sorry. Meant 'true'.

Comment: what puzzles me that I have setup an actionn bar with size 0 so everything is hidden under three dots menu. 

when wlset.=true ->in action bar I have wl.settings and nothing else
                  =false-> I have my defined actions in it and no wl.settings.
how is it possible that both version are displaying things in the same place(under the three dots) when once is Action bar and once it is options menu. Hopefully my explanation is not too messy.

Comment: The options menu is a full page of options (like text field, knobs, etc), whereas the actor bar is a pop-up menu - you cannot contain the two together.

Comment: See my mention of the get/set server URL API in 6.3. That's what you should do.

Comment: Yeah the mention is great is just that for now I work on 6.2

I now its a full page I just want to have an action bar with the link to wl.settings. Action bar should look like this.
action 1
action 2
action 3
worklight settings

Comment: I don't know how supported is that. As said, Action Bar in itself is an unsupported feature. Note that Worklight Settings is not meant for production time. It is for development only.

Comment: Idan, can I also ask is there a possible way how to initialize the worklight settings other than through app.descriptor (<worklightSettings include="true"/>) can I somehow create an action for a button that calls the exact same worklight setting action ?

or  the only way to do this is your link at your very first answer ?
thanks

Comment: Worklight Settings page can be enabled only through application-descriptor.xml; In Android it will work only up to API Level 13. You can control the server URL via API only starting 6.3. With that API you can incorporate it however you'd like.